# Matlab : find min value and save index from some matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, min

Supposed I have matrix :

```
mat= [1 2 3;
      2 3 4;
      3 4 5;]

test = [2 3 4 5 6 7;
        3 4 5 6 7 8;
        7 8 9 4 5 6 ]
```

All I want to do is do these operations:

```
mat1=[(1-2) (2-3) (3-4);
      (2-3) (3-4) (4-5);
      (3-7) (4-8) (5-9)]
```

and

```
mat2=[(1-5) (2-6) (3-7);
      (2-6) (3-7) (4-8);
      (3-4) (4-5) (5-6)]
```

and save the min value between `mat1` and `mat2` then save the index of the value from.
I want my answers like these :

```
ans = [-4 -4 -4;
       -4 -4 -4;
       -4 -4 -4]
index = [2 2 2;
         2 2 2;
         1 1 1]
```

I dont need to save `mat1` and `mat2`, I just need `ans` and `index` (to make the computation faster). Is there any help how to code it? Thank you.

Comment: I see where matrix `ans` comes from but I'm confused how you compute `index`. As a first step, you can calculate `mat1` and `mat2` by doing `[mat mat] - test` and then splitting the result into two halves.

Comment: index save the path where the min-value comes from, that means which matrix that gives the min value, mat1 or mat2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [**`bsxfun`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) like this for a generalized case.

**Code**

```
%%// Slightly bigger example than the original one
mat= [
    1 2 3 6;
    2 3 4 2;
    3 4 5 3;]

test = [
    2 3 4 8 5 6 7 1;
    3 4 5 3 6 7 8 7;
    7 8 9 6 4 5 6 3]

[M,N] = size(mat);
[M1,N1] = size(test);

if N1~=2*N %%// Check if the sizes allow for the required op to be performed
    error('Operation could not be performed');
end

[min_vals,index] = min(bsxfun(@minus,mat,reshape(test,M,N,2)),[],3)
```

**Output**

```
min_vals =
    -4    -4    -4    -2
    -4    -4    -4    -5
    -4    -4    -4    -3

index =
     2     2     2     1
     2     2     2     2
     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: +1 for cleverness and "density". But not sure that that always makes for the clearest answer (because it makes it hard to read, and this can lead to problems down the line - for example if someone else looks at your code 6 months later).

Comment: @Floris My workflow for later lookups would involve breaking down into parts and it works in most cases :) Thanks btw!

Answer (score 2):

```
mat1 = mat-test(:,1:3)
mat2 = mat-test(:,4:end)
theMin = bsxfun(@min,mat1,mat2)

-4    -4    -4
-4    -4    -4
-4    -4    -4
```

To build the index

```
idx = mat2-mat1;
I2  = find(idx<=0);
I1  = find(idx>0);
idx(I2) = 2; 
idx(I1) = 1;

     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think these four lines will do it

```
matDifs = bsxfun(@minus, mat, reshape(test, 3, 3, 2)); % construct the two difference matrices
values = min(matDifs, [], 3); % minimum value along third dimension
indices = ones(size(values)); % create matrix of indices: start out with ones
indices(matDifs(:,:,2)<matDifs(:,:,1)) = 2; % set some indices to 2
```

This does almost the same thing as @Divakar's solution. It is less compact but slightly more readable, I think.